# SQLite3 EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

When I try to insert data to sqlite database, Sometimes its get error message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS".please check and help to solve this issue.

Thanking you all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are u use multi-thread handle the sqlite. use [NSThread currentThread] check your current thread. if you Use multiple threads to operate it. i suggest you could use 
@synchronized or FMDB to ensure at the same time there is only one thread to operate it.